# Test question regarding grep

Tags: grep, c

Below is a the test question for a practice LPIC-1 exam I took.  The correct answer is A.  I'm really dazzled at how this is the case.  If it's not too much trouble can someone walk me through how A is the correct answer?

```
int double(int n)
    { /* int arg, int return */
       return n*2;
    }
    char hello(int n)
    { /* int arg, char return */
       printf("hello %i\n", n);
    }
    int five()
    { /* no args, int return */
       return 5;
    }
    int        triple(int n, int other, char nonsense)
    { /* int arg, int return */
       return n*3;
    }
```

> Correctly parsing a C source file requires a full-fledged parser (such as that built into a C compiler). Nonetheless, regular expressions can be used to provide a pretty good approximate descriptions of many program constructs. Which of the following searches will locate at least most of the C functions that accept an int as a first argument, and return an int (and will not produce false positives very often). The exhibit contains a fragment of C code with several annotated matching and non-matching functions (for non-C programmers).
>
> - A. `grep -E "int[ \t]+\w+[ \t]*\([ \t]*int" *.c`
> - B. `grep -E "^int\w+[A-Za-z_]+\w*\(\w*int" *.c`
> - C. `grep -E "int.+\([ \t]+int.*\) " *.c`
> - D. `grep -E "int[ \t]+[A-Za-z_][ \t]+\(int" *.c`

Reference: http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/exam101.html - specifically this question - 1.3/7/1.

Comment: I advise reading the core appontments for the corresponding LPIC levels and trying to understang it. You might be in for a disappointment if you thing doing mock exams does cut it. Some of the LPI tests are a bit unusual, my LPI 201 focused a lot in Linux network knowledge.

Comment: http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/exam101.html - it's this Q - 1.3/7/1.

Comment: always use a tool or build your own graph of the regexp: https://regexper.com/

Comment: Bonus points could be given to  those pointing out that you shouldn't use `double` as the name of a function as that's one of the builtin C types. Or that `[ \t]` matches on space, backslash and `t` instead of the intended TAB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So "A." is the answer simply because it's the only one that returns the 2 functions defined in the sample code:

```
$ grep -E "int[ \t]+\w+[ \t]*\([ \t]*int" sample.c
int double(int n)
    int        triple(int n, int other, char nonsense)
```

The other 3 return nothing, if you were to try them. This one works because it's able to deal with both situations that present in these lines:

```
int double(int n)
    int        triple(int n, int other, char nonsense)
```

The `grep`:

- `int[ \t]+` - matches lines that begin with `int` followed by at least 1 space  or tab (`\t`)
- `\w+` - this matches one or more characters in a word (double & triple)
- `[ \t]*` - zero or more spaces or tabs
- `\([ \t]*int` - a open paren (`(`) followed by zero or more spaces or tabs followed by the string `int`

**NOTE:** the question assumes GNU `grep` since it's utilizing `\w`. Other implementations of `grep` do not support this notation with their regex (`-E`), for these, using `[[:alnum:]]` is the better choice. Also a wiser choice would've been `[[:blank:]]` instead of `[ \t]` since technically this matches spaces, backslashes, and t as POSIX requires.

Rewriting the "A." answer this is a much more compliant solution:

```
$ grep -E "int[[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]+[[:blank:]]*\([[:blank:]]*int" sample.c
```

Here you can see in red what the above `grep` actually matched:

[image: ss2]

Comment: A C function name may match `[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]+` in the C locale.

Comment: @Kusalananda - you're turning into Stephane 8-) - so this? `grep -E "int[[:blank:]]+[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]+[[:blank:]]*\([[:blank:]]*int" sample.c`.

Comment: Oh, I hope not. I don't know what Stéphane would have said, but it looks ok to me...

Comment: Why does "[ \t]* - zero or more spaces or tabs" have an astrix at the end, isn't that a wildcard?

Comment: @user284179 no it's a count against the set of characters in the square brackets, means zero or more of the things inside the set. Also per POSIX the set is actually space, backslash, or t which is technically incorrect per our conversations.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that when you take the test, you can't actually run the `grep` commands against the input data, then you will have to look at the expressions and do some guessing.

Looking at them in reverse order:

- D. `grep -E "int[ \t]+[A-Za-z_][ \t]+\(int" *.c`

  This does not allow for function names longer than a single character (`[A-Za-z_]`) and assumes that there must be at least a space, backslash or `t` between the function name and the argument list.

  Matches `int a (int` or `int at(int` but not `int foo(int`.
- C. `grep -E "int.+\([ \t]+int.*\) " *.c`

  This assumes that the argument list starts with at least one space, backslash or `t`.

  Matches `int foo( int` or `int foo(tint` but not `int foo(int`.
- B. `grep -E "^int\w+[A-Za-z_]+\w*\(\w*int" *.c`

  This does not allow for any space between the `int` return type and the function name, and it assumes that the function definition starts at the start of the line (the example code contains some indented function definitions).

  Matches `intfoo(int` but not `int foo(int`.
- A. `grep -E "int[ \t]+\w+[ \t]*\([ \t]*int" *.c`

  This is the only one that allows a match on `int foo(int`, but it also matches invalid function names such as `int 000(int`.  It is however the best regular expression out of the four given ones.

Note too that this question assumes GNU `grep` for matching `\w`.  With a standard `grep` implementation `[[:alnum:]_]` would have been better for `\w` and `[[:blank:]]` should have been used in place of for matching space or tab (`[ \t]` matches space, backslash or `t`).

Comment: Note that it's fine to match on `int \w+` since `int 000` would not occur in C code (other than in things like `char *p = "int 000(int)"` but that's the kind of thing that would fool `int [a-zA-Z_]\w*` as well).